# Android SQL database error

Tags: android, database

I have got a code to pass the values of the rating bar to the sql database. I am not sure why when I press my button submit, the program crashes.

```
public class wReview extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

       RatingBar rSimple, rSafety, rOverall;
       Button submit;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_review);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rSubmit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.rSubmit:

            String simple = String.valueOf(rSimple.getRating());
            String Safety = String.valueOf(rSafety.getRating());
            String Overall = String.valueOf(rOverall.getRating());

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String rowID = extras.getString("id");

            reviewDB reviewdb = new reviewDB(this);
            reviewdb.open();
            long l = Long.parseLong(rowID);
            String name = reviewdb.getname(l);
            reviewdb.createEntry(name,simple,Safety,Overall);
            reviewdb.close();

            break;
        }

    }

}
```

My database entry should be correct, is there anything wrong with the way I create entry for my database??

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SIMPLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SAFETY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_OVERALL + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    ); 

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public reviewDB(Context c)
    {
        ourContext= c;
    }

    public reviewDB open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        reviewDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String name, String simple,String safety,String overall) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_SIMPLE, simple);
        cv.put(KEY_SAFETY, safety);
        cv.put(KEY_OVERALL, overall);
        return reviewDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
```

Logcat:

```
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855): Process: com.example.packageit, PID: 1855
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at com.example.packageit.wReview.onClick(wReview.java:38)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-05 16:03:22.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post stack trace. We don't know what is happening.

Comment: And what the logcat says?

What is the name for ROW_ID column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables `rSimple` `rSafety` `rOverall` have not been correctly initialised, and are all `null`. Your code will crash with a null pointer exception when you try to invoke `rSimple.getRating()`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.rSubmit:

        String simple = String.valueOf(rSimple.getRating());
        ...
```

Comment: omg, sorry I totally forget about that. I added the line 
  rSimple = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rSimple);
  rSafety = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rSafety);
  rOverall = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rOverall);

but there is still a problem with the code